# Tween Animation Error

Tags: android

Necesito ayuda con una animacion que estoy usando.

El codigo de animacion en un archivo XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.4"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.6"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="700" />
<set
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="700">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.4"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.6"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="-45"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

y el codigo en el activity

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Animation hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
image.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
```

Es el mismo codigo que esta en la misma guia de android. Y es que lo estoy usando como prueba. Pero me termina mostrando un error:

> -------- beginning of crash 05-13 07:13:04.142 2682-2682/com.example.chvid.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.chvid.myapplication, PID: 2682
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.chvid.myapplication/com.example.chvid.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at
>   com.example.chvid.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  05-13
>   07:13:18.865 2682-2682/com.example.chvid.myapplication I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 2682 SIG: 9

De antemano, agradezco enormemente toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mismo mensaje de error lo especifica:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)'
>   on a null object

El problema es que al tratar de obtener la referencia del ImageView, no existe y devuelve nulo.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Asegura que el ImageView se encuentre en el Layout que cargas en el `setContentView();`

Si no tienes algún error al compilar es porque la vista ImageView en realidad existe pero no en el Layout en donde intentas obtener la referencia.

Answer (score 1):

Has comprobado que this es el contexto correcto? prueba a utilizar getContext() en su lugar y comprueba que el xml de la animación hyperspace_jump se encuentra en la ruta correcta de la carpeta de recursos de android